# Using PDFLaTeX inside C# .Net code does not load some math symbols

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, miktex, tex-core

On my Windows 8.1 with MikTeK installed, the following C# code successfully generates a PDF file with Math expressions except for some Unicode codes such as plusminus sign:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "pdflatex.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = Test.tex;
```

For example, in my tex file I've two math expressions one \sqrt{2} with square root symbol and one a\unicode{177}b with plusminus sign. The above code correctly displays square root sign in the resulting PDF file but the expression with plusminus sign displays as a<177>b. The error shown in the corresponding Test.log file generated by MikTeK is shown below. The error is `UC: bad: 177`. The same tex file correctly displays math expressions when directly using the DOS command in Windows as `pdflatex Test.tex`:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 19.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 19.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
UC: bad: 177
[1....
```

**UPDATE**
I'm using a tex file generated via [David's stylesheet](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/tree/master/pmml2tex). The entire content of the file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pmml-new}
\begin{document}

 \(\let\par\empty

a\unicode{177}b

\)

\end{document}
```

When using pdflatex inside C# code (shown above) I get the following pdf: [image]. But the same tex file correctly generates the pdf shown below when using the command `pdflatex Test.tex` in the DOS window or when using TeXworks editor: [image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `a \pm b`?

Comment: @ArunDebray I'm using David Carlisle's stylesheet that is using \unicode{...} for symbols.

Comment: the error message is from latex, so all the description and C# can not be relevant, please just post a small latex file that gives that error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Per your request I've posted the latex file along with an `Update` section in my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not say but this is `pmml-new.sty` which sets up a mechanism to declare behaviour for unicode characters but leaves most undefined. You need to define 177 as \pm so

```
 \@namedef{uc177}{\pm}
```

should define this character.

Comment: I've added an `Update` section in my original post. `\@namedef{uc177}{\pm}` is included in the `pmm-new.sty` and the tex file correctly generates the PDF with math expression in question when using DOS command or Texworks editor.

Comment: @nam check the paths in the log file, presumably you are picking up different versions of the style without that definition.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. It's working now. You may want to add your above comment to your `Answer`. I had included `\@namedef{uc177}{\pm} `in the file `pmml-new.sty` that is the part of .NET project but that change was not reflecting in the Output directory of the project because the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the file was not set to `Copy if newer` hence the project build was still using the older version during the build. [Ref: See the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940011/why-copy-if-newer-replaces-not-only-when-a-file-in-the-output-dir-is-older)

Comment: For benefit of other readers of this post: Please note that the response from `David Carlisle` and his comments above - regarding what I may be missing - I had resolved the issue. I was just revisiting the post for another related task of mine, and noticed that I had not marked David's response as an `Answer`.